# Can't find any way to filter by multiple columns using "bootstrap-tables"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I recently came across "bootstrap-tables" which I like cz of the design options.
Everything works just like the original datatables version, except one of the most important things: being able to search in multiple columns simultaneously. For example, taking a look at my code, if I enter into the searchbar "Action Abenteuer", on the original datatables script, it then shows me all entries with both of these properties. But when I use the bootstrap version, after typing "Action A" it shows no results at all. Also when you type "Action" and then a spacebar, it automatically deletes the space after like 1 second. I don't get it, this is one of the best and most important features of datatables, it can't be that complicated to just adapt this to the bootstrap version? for an experienced developer.. which I ain't..

I got 2 scripts, one using the original datatables lib, and the second one using the bootstrap-table version. I've spent days trying to find a solution I'm really losing hope.. There has been several requests on the github repo, but still no working solution. Someone please help me out.

Here is my raw datatables version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>tabletest</title>
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titel</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Subgenre</th>
                <th>Bewertung</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>Action</td>
                <td>Psycho</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul</td>
                <td>Comedy</td>
                <td>Sport</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Action</td>
                <td>Psycho</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Action</td>
                <td>Abenteuer</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Helen</td>
                <td>Comedy</td>
                <td>Sport</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            "dom": 'f'
            } );
        } );
        
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

#####################################################################################################

And here is my second code the bootstrap-tables version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TestTable</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="assets/css/fresh-bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap_table/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="fresh-table full-color-orange">

                        <table id="mytable" data-search="true">
                            <thead>
                                <th data-field="Titel" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                                <th data-field="Genre" data-sortable="true">Genre</th>
                                <th data-field="Sub" data-sortable="true">Sub</th>
                                <th data-field="Bewertung" data-sortable="true">Rating</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Peter</td>
                                    <td>Action</td>
                                    <td>Psycho</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Paul</td>
                                    <td>Action</td>
                                    <td>Abenteuer</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Mary</td>
                                    <td>Comedy</td>
                                    <td>Abenteuer</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>John</td>
                                    <td>Action</td>
                                    <td>Abenteuer</td>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Mike</td>
                                    <td>Comedy</td>
                                    <td>Psycho</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Helen</td>
                                    <td>Comedy</td>
                                    <td>Abenteuer</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var $table = $('#mytable')

    $(function () {
        $table.bootstrapTable({
            classes: 'table table-hover table-striped',
            search: true,
            striped: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageSize: 8,
        })
    })
</script>

</html>
```

I've tried so many different things, I can't even remember them all... It seems like there's no solution to this problem..

I think, initially, when the author started writing "bootstrap-tables", the original datatables lib also couldn't do this yet. But in the latest version, it can search for multiple columns. So maybe it's just a matter of changing a few lines in his code? Also tried texting him but no replies..